# Como puedo colocar un modal que se muestre al 50% del scroll?

Tags: javascript, modal, scroll

estoy intentando colocar un modal que se muestre al scrollear hasta el 50% de la pagina. Intente utilizando

```
<script>

    window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
        const scrollable = document.documentElement.scrollHeight - window.innerHeight;
        const scrolled = window.scrollY;



        if (Math.ceil(scrolled) === (scrollable / 2)) {
            alert('You reached 50%!');
        }
    });

</script>
```

Pero no puedo encontrar manera de lograrlo.

Answer (score 0):

El problema es en la condición `if(Math.ceil(scrolled) === (scrollable / 2))`, prácticamente nunca va a resultar verdadero, estás comparando valor y tipo (al usar 3 signos igual), pero el primer elemento es entero y el segundo podría ser de punto flotante.

Tal vez si aplicas también `Math.ceil()` a la división en algún momento podría resultar verdadera la condición, pero va a ser muy difícil que el evento se dispare exactamente al llegar al 50% del *scroll*.

Te sugiero agregar una variable para que la ventana (o alerta) se muestre solo una vez y que en la comparación revises si el desplazamiento actual es mayor o igual que la mitad del desplazamiento disponible:

```js
// Agregar variable para que solo se muestre una vez
let reached = false;
window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
    const scrollable = document.documentElement.scrollHeight - window.innerHeight;
    const scrolled = window.scrollY;

    if(!reached && Math.ceil(scrolled) >= Math.ceil(scrollable / 2)) {
        // Evitar que se vuelva a mostrar
        reached = true;
        alert('You reached 50%!');
    }
});
```

```css
p { margin: 100px 20px; }
```

```html
<p>Texto para llenar la pantalla</p>
<p>Texto para llenar la pantalla</p>
<p>Texto para llenar la pantalla</p>
<p>Texto para llenar la pantalla</p>
<p>Texto para llenar la pantalla</p>
<p>Texto para llenar la pantalla</p>
<p>Texto para llenar la pantalla</p>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias! Me ayudo mucho tu respuesta. Estoy recién comenzando y hay aspecto técnicos que a veces no me doy cuenta o no presto la atención necesaria.